# How to test google nearby on ِAVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, google-nearby

I am currently working on a project using google nearby connection technology, but unfortunately this technology needs more than one real device .. Is there a way to test this service provided by Google through AVD ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. The emulators don't properly support Bluetooth, which is a requirement for Nearby Connections.

Comment: Is there other way to test nearby by one device?

Comment: You could test through unit tests. Outside of seeing that startAdvertising and startDiscovery don't crash, I can't think of any other way to test with just one device. Have you ever used Robolectric? I can help you with writing some Robolectric Shadows for Nearby Connections, which will mock out all the radio behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge the actual emulators don't propose any Google Nearby emulation, because there are some behaviors they lack, like the `Peer Discovery`.

In @SpiralsTeam, we've developed a platform called **[Androfleet](https://github.com/m3ftah/androfleet)** to support Android WiFi Direct emulation, which works like Google Nearby Connections API ( as it is supposed to give an abstraction layer over BLE, Bluetooth, **WiFi Direct** and ultrasonic connections).

For the moment, we are extending **[Androfleet](https://github.com/m3ftah/androfleet)** to support Google Nearby emulation.

If you have any special case of use / suggestions, please file an issue in the Github repository, and we will take it into consideration in our development.

We are welcoming contributors to the project.

As many developers need to test their Google Nearby Apps, we really need to serve this ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to test Nearby on Virtual Device, which is using one real mobile device at least and the other is Virtual Device is a device that supports Bluetooth and I have tried a lot and which it has worked with me is [android-x86_64-6.0-r3](http://bdownload.fosshub.com/programs/android-x86_64-6.0-r3.iso)

Comment: Link is broken((

Comment: Yes it's broken :( what emulated phone are you using?

Comment: https://osdn.net/projects/android-x86/downloads/65890/android-x86_64-6.0-r3.iso/